# Distinct values one column with other columns from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, distinct-values

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate rows from an Access dataset made up of two tables table1 and table2. I want to retrieve the distinct values from one column and fields from two tables, but also retrieve the values of other columns of duplicates and unique values.

Sample data (not actual data):

Table 1:

```
ID  BOM_PART_NAME  PART FIND NO  POS  LCN  POS_CT   
1       E              0001       1    P0    1
2       A              0002       1    P1    1
3       C              0003       1    P2    1
4       D              0004       1    P3    1
5       F              0005       1    P4    1
```

Table 2:

```
ID  PART-ATA-NO    PART-SN     PART-NAME
1      001                         A
2      002                         B
3      003                         C
4      004          1100           D
5      005          1101           E
```

Table 2:

ID  PART-ATA-NO    PART-SN     PART-NAME
1      001                         A
2      002                         B
3      003                         C
4      004          1100           D
5      005          1101           E

What I'm getting (just showing major columns in result set to keep brief):

ID ... PART FIND NO       POS       PART-ATA-NO   PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
3        003              1           003          1101
3        003              1           003          1102
4        003              2           003          1101
4        003              2           003          1102
5        004              1           004          1101
5        004              1           004          1102
Desired Result:

ID    PART FIND NO       POS      PART-ATA-NO     PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
4        003              2           003          1101
5        003              3           003          1102
6        003              4           003          1103
7        003              5           003          1104
8        004              1           004          1105
9        004              2           004          1106

```
ID    PART FIND NO       POS       PART-ATA-NO   PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
3        003              1           003          1101  
3        003              1           003          1102
4        003              2           003          1101
4        003              2           003          1102
5        004              1           004          1101
5        004              1           004          1102
```

Desired Result:

```
ID    PART FIND NO       POS      PART-ATA-NO     PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
4        003              2           003          1101  
5        003              3           003          1102
6        003              4           003          1103
7        003              5           003          1104
8        004              1           004          1105
9        004              2           004          1106
```

With matching PART FIND NO's (and PART-ATA-NO's), POS should be incremented by 1. The SN's should all be unique.

The query I used to join the two tables:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.[PART-ATA-NO], Table2.[PART-SN]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[PART FIND NO] = Table2.[PART-ATA-NO];
```

The field I want unique values from is `[PART-SN]` from `table2`. I want to select all other fields from `table1` and `[PART-SN]` from `table 2`, of which all rows should be returned for all distinct rows of `[PART-SN]`. `[PART FIND NO]` and `[PART-ATA-NO]` have equivalent values. Is there a way to join the two tables to get this result?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Added some sample data and expected result

Comment: You said there are 2 source tables, I see only one. The issue about calculating an incrementing value addressed in your other question.

Comment: Yeah, but I found the issue wasn't actually that field. That issue seems to be a result of duplicating the SN's. These are the two tables joined together but not all the fields as the tables are very large.